# I have two interfaces and I would like to merge only the ids of the interfaces

Tags: typescript

I am trying to update a property that nested Inside an array of objects and that object has another array of objects. In order to update the property I need the Ids (or indexes) of both arrays to update the property. So I created the interfaces:

```js
export interface ILaser {
    id: 'L1' | 'L2' | 'L3' | 'L4' | 'L5' | 'L6';
    name:
        | 'Laser #1'
        | 'Laser #2'
        | 'Laser #3'
        | 'Laser #4'
        | 'Laser #5'
        | 'Laser #6';
    switchMode: Number;
    pulseWidth: Number;
    power: Boolean;
}

export interface IOpticalHeadUnit {
    id: 'OHU1' | 'OHU2' | 'OHU3';
    name:
        | 'Optical Head Unit #1'
        | 'Optical Head Unit #2'
        | 'Optical Head Unit #3';
    lasers: Array<ILaser>;
}
```

I want to update the power of the laser inside the optical head unit.
I created a function to get both ids and update the power, but I need now to create a third interface to correct the ts error, but I only want the ids of both interfaces so if i add another laser or Optical head unit I won't have to update in both locations.

Something like this:

```js
interface ILaserIdAndIOpticalUnitId{
laserId: ILaser.id;
opticalHeadUnitId: IOpticalHeadUnit.id;
```

Is it possible to accomplish in typescript?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the usage of interfaces. Interfaces do not store values and therefore you cannot retrieve data from it. Interfaces are simply a contract saying that any object that implements said interfaces complies to the contract it has laid out. I believe what you are attempting here is using interfaces as classes. If I misunderstand, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use square bracket notation, just like in plain js:

```js
export interface ILaser {
    id: 'L1' | 'L2' | 'L3' | 'L4' | 'L5' | 'L6';
    name:
    | 'Laser #1'
    | 'Laser #2'
    | 'Laser #3'
    | 'Laser #4'
    | 'Laser #5'
    | 'Laser #6';
    switchMode: Number;
    pulseWidth: Number;
    power: Boolean;
}

export interface IOpticalHeadUnit {
    id: 'OHU1' | 'OHU2' | 'OHU3';
    name:
    | 'Optical Head Unit #1'
    | 'Optical Head Unit #2'
    | 'Optical Head Unit #3';
    lasers: Array<ILaser>;
}

interface ILaserIdAndIOpticalUnitId {
    laserId: ILaser['id'];
    opticalHeadUnitId: IOpticalHeadUnit['id']
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210910#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBlMBnNOAbwCg5bEATALjgHJCBGFuAH1cICYuvNgGYhfACzi2AVmmEAbCwDcNOkkwBbYIzW1hxMlDgBiTnp59S5E4IsHrxk2PtWjpqa7aPTcr4ZslVTo4EgB3BBhsAAsAWQh6HTgAOQBXTQAjNGC6MFSAGzIAdQR6GGjmNMzsi0gwtGYAIQgIfOBMJFUAXyoqUEhYRBQ0LFwCAHkwGARsTHyACXb6AFUkSMoLUuYWcfnlzksdvcFD3eWxHNoNbV0Q4Unp2fy4Rcx6OFX1sxYvB5m5l5LD5reC2H53Vh-J6At7Ar4XCz5RwkZgAQSgUEwAE8ADxERwAPm6vWQqAwODw%20KM%20HoqKQ9HwULmnxgNI2ISR1KYBACUAA2ixSiwALqXOAQKb-BZLFk05iMyVPV4rEECoXCqhdIA)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for and the playground was a great bonus, I checked it out there and it works like I wanted to

Answer (score 2):

A simple fix using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
interface ILaserIdAndIOpticalUnitId {
  laserId: ILaser['id'];
  opticalHeadUnitId: IOpticalHeadUnit['id'];
}

const foo: ILaserIdAndIOpticalUnitId = {
  laserId: 'L1',
  opticalHeadUnitId: 'OHU1'
};
```

Out of curiosity, an intersection type:

```
type ID = ILaser['id'] | IOpticalHeadUnit['id'];
const foo: ID = 'L1';
const bar: ID = 'OHU1';
```